# How will supply ripple affect OCXO performance?

Tags: power-supply, oscillator, ldo

To feed 3.3V/1.5A to my [IQOV-164](http://www.iqdfrequencyproducts.com/products/details/iqov-164-1-30.pdf), I wonder if I should go for a low noise LDO with 6uV RMS noise or, to the other extreme, if I can simply feed supply voltage from a step-down converter with 20mV ripple.

Design goal is good short-term stability, long-term is not a concern (I am aware that IQOV-164 may not be the best choice for this objective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret the [datasheet](http://www.iqdfrequencyproducts.com/products/details/iqov-164-1-30.pdf) as saying the variation is worst-case 25ppb (50% of 50ppb) for variation between 3.13 and 3.47V.

That's not a whole lot, but I guess if you are using an ovenized oscillator you do care about stability. It is, however, typical that the sensitivity to high frequency noise will be **much** higher than low frequency ('DC') changes. At a minimum I would expect more phase noise.

[Here](http://www.conwin.com/pdfs/AN2093.pdf) is a brief app note from another maker- they do suggest that LC filters may be required in the power supply and that good layout is important.

20mV is pretty bad. 6uV RMS (maybe 40uV p-p) is very low.

Comment: Though  just because the LDO is spec'd for 6uV of noise doesn't mean that that's the worst output variation you're going to see.  If you feed the LDO with a switcher that has 20mV of ripple at frequency X you have to look at the LDO's PSRR at the switching frequency to see how much of that ripple will pass through to the output.  Probably a lot more than 6uV for a high frequency switcher.

Comment: @Spehro: I agree, 50% probably means 25ppb. 50% variation on nominal frequency does not sound reasonable.

Comment: @JohnD Absolutely. And layout can contribute greatly. A passive filter ahead of the regulator could help a lot.

Comment: EN6337QI has indeed quite an amount of ripple @ 1.9MHz. Following your advice, I will add a ferrite bead (after output caps), then bulk cap, then TPS7A8300. Load transients should not be a concern here, so a bead should do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on Spehro's answer-  After re-reading the datasheet I think it's correct to say that the 50% is 50% of 50ppb.  My original interpretation doesn't seem like it would be a very practical product.  However, the recommendation for an LDO still seems valid.

I would say based on the wording below in the datasheet that this part is very sensitive to supply variation:

Supply Voltage Variation (measurement referenced to
frequency observed with TA=25°C, Vs varied from 3.13V to
3.47V, VC=1.65V/NC and load=50Ω/15pF): ±50% of frequency
stability

There is likely a frequency dependence to the supply rejection, so we can't assume that the DC rejection ratio applies to switching supply ripple (it could be better or worse) but by extrapolation 20mV*147 %/V = about +/-3% frequency variation.  I'd go with a good low-noise LDO.

Answer (score 0):

From the datasheet I see:

[image]

Assuming a linear supply variation response, you could get 0.5/(3.47V-3.13V)*20mV = 0.029 or about 3% variation. This sounds like a lot of short term stability variation to me.

I would recommend an LDO. I am curious however, where did you get the ripple spec for an LDO? It's not a switching circuit.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP means 6uV of noise, over some given bandwidth- not periodic ripple.

Comment: @Daniel: You are correct, the LDO spec says 6uV RMS noise on output, which is not the same as 6uV ripple. My design uses TPS7A8300, I was just wondering if this is overkill.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think it would be overkill to add the low-noise LDO. I also agree with the comment about the stability spec to be 50% of 50ppb

Answer (score 0):

Considering the time to heat up OCXO to operating temperature, any ripple even if 10% >1000Hz would have no effect on temperature.

Consider power dissipation is a function of DC not AC ripple and thermistor feedback regulates the OCXO temperature will be fast <1kHz so any noise above this has no effect.

But if DC steady state is stated as [image]

- Say the OCXO stability is rated at 1e-9 (1ppb) and 50% of this is 5e-10
- Then the DC nominal (3.47+2.13)/2=Vnom=2.8V
- The difference is (3.47-2.13)=1.34V
- The Sensitivity is then 5e-10/1.34  or 37 [ppb/Volt] for DC
- The sensitivity for Fout above x kHz Vs ripple is null. ( except for phase noise perhaps )

  ### - The assumption is thermal shift is zero using assumed large thermal time constant of at least 30 seconds measured over xx microseconds of 1 ripple cycle.
- warmup time is 3 minutes max.

Comment: Phase noise is a concern, long term accuracy less so. I must admit this OCXO is not optimized towards low phase noise, I choose it because it is quite affordable.

Comment: @Tony Stewart It seem that you are focusing on output changes due to temperature fluctuations though. However, if the supply changes it seems to me that you will have some effect on the output frequency even before the temperature stabilizes at the new operating point.